# How to add accessibility to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to add accessibility to RecyclerView. I have 7 items in the RecyclerView and I want talkback to read them all at once.

Here is my recycler view widget. Please advice. attribute `importantforaccessibility= "yes"` not helping.

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_section"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
          app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Recycler adapter view is as follows :

```
class ExitRowAgreementAdapter(val items: List<String>, val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ExitRowAgreementAdapter.ExitRowViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExitRowViewHolder {
        return ExitRowViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.row_items,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExitRowViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.txtExitRowItem.text = items.get(position)

    }


    inner class ExitRowViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val txtExitRowItem = view.txt_exit_row_item
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess, you need to add accessibility to recyclerview childs. i.e, to the adapter of the recyclerView

Comment: you in in xml of child?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should add importantForAccessibility to the RecycleView as well as his children:

Parent layout:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/provider_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            ***  android:importantForAccessibility="yes"   ***
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />
```

And in the item view:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle"
   **** android:focusable="true" ****
   **** android:importantForAccessibility="yes"  ****>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

---

Also, I had problems with the list navigation so I added this method to the recyclerView in order to keep the focused item at the top.

In your activity/fragment:

```
recyclerView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
            @Override
            public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup host, View child, AccessibilityEvent event) {
                int position;
                switch (event.getEventType()) {
                    case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED:
                        position = (Integer) child.getTag();
                        ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 100);

                        break;
                }

                return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host, child, event);
            }
        });
```

In the recyclerView adapter:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       .....
        holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    }
```

---

This post helped me a lot if you want to go deeper: https://android.jlelse.eu/accessibility-and-staggered-grid-layout-8e01a753aada

Answer (score 0):

you should set adapter for recycler as you have done that.
in the recycler adapter you have list by making it public or setting getter you can have access to your list.

Comment: I am setting the adapter as above. Since I need to read all list items at once as I am passing list of string in adapter so what changes I need to do?

Comment: I tried adding content description in adapter but it is not serving my purpose. holder.txtExitRowItem?.contentDescription = items.get(position)   ...... My aim is to read complete recycler view all at once that means 7 lines all at once